# Is there a user-friendly way to set the application used by MS Office's "XML Editor" to open non-Office XML files?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

Excel and Word files in the [Microsoft Office 2003 XML format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_2003_XML_formats) use the file extension ".xml". Microsoft Office sets Windows's handler for ".xml" files to a special application "XML Editor" which opens the files in Excel or Word based on the "mso-application" tag in the XML file's header. If the tag is not present, it opens it in some other application which can deal with XML files, which by default is Internet Explorer. How does one change this in a user-friendly way from Internet Explorer to a different application? (While maintaining the behavior that Office 2003 XML files are opened in Office.)

I already found out from [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569102/whats-the-best-way-for-an-app-on-windows-to-assocaite-itself-with-a-particular-f/1569619#1569619) that the "some other application" setting can be configured through the registry. But I'm looking for a solution that is more convenient to end-users than having to ask them to fiddle with the registry.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to right click and do 'open with', this is probably the safest way for end users to open xml files in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I'm afraid I really need an answer to my question as stated, and not a workaround. Also, why the link to the “Liquid XML Editor” application? Can you please give some more info on how it's relevant to my question or your answer?